# Prevent opening multiple instances of VB application

Tags: vb6, multiple-instances

My VB6 application is backed by a MS Access database. Allowing user to open multiple instances of the application would create conflicts & alter connected database.

Ideal solution would be to focus existing instance if user tries to open new one.

How can I attain this?

Comment: The term you need is "single instance application".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `App.PrevInstance`:

```
'this code would be in a bas module for start up.'
Private Sub main()
    'Check for previous instance and exit if found.'

    Dim rc As Long

    If App.PrevInstance Then
        rc = MsgBox("Application is already running", vbCritical, App.Title)
        Exit Sub
    Else
        frmMain.Show
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly, now is there anyway to set focus to current instance instead of showing error message..?

Comment: Yeah, use the `AppActivate` method - pass in whatever's in the title bar of your application.