# How to Open Already Running instance using vb6.0?

Tags: vb6, windows-services

I have created one service for my vb6.0 application with user credentials. It is running background. But i manually click the exe from application folder,No need to create a new instance, need to open the already running service instance GUI window.

Can you please give me the solution for this?

Comment: what you mean exactly with _"user credentials"_ ? if two users will log in, are they both allowed to start just one instance each of your "exe-as-service"?

Comment: user credentials means local system credentials.

Comment: I think you will need to use the App.PrevInstance property to detect this. Some approaches then use Win32 API calls to look for the application window and bring it to the foreground.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent opening multiple instance of VB application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468616/prevent-opening-multiple-instance-of-vb-application)

Comment: @DaveInCaz: maybe this question is slightly different, because App. PrevInstance doesn't work across the user boundary, so it isn't useful at machine-level. Anyway, this question still remains unclear until further explanation...